# app.post() does not register POST request

Tags: node.js, forms

I am new to POST methods and I have been getting stuck on this problem where it seems that app.post() doesn't work. I have followed a handful of tutorials to try and understand the problem but I have no clue what could be the problem. I may have misunderstood something in the tutorials or made a very obvious mistake.

I have tried to make an HTML form that gives its data to the server through POST. It seems that the problem is the server not reading the data because I can see on the developer tools that the POST is sent and I have also managed to get the data with a PHP server.

My HTML script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>schoolpartygames.tv</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/code-screen.css" type="text/css"/>
    
    
  </head>
  
  <body style="background-color: #00A6FF;">
    <p class="title">Schoolpartygames.tv</p>
    
    <form action="/Joining" method="post" onsubmit="return checkRoomCode();"> 
      <input class="text" type="text" maxlength="24" name="UserName" id="UserName" placeholder="Enter Username Here"> 
      <input class="text" type="text" maxlength="6" name="roomCode" id="roomCode" placeholder="Enter Room Code Here">
      <button class="joinbutton" type="submit">JOIN</button>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

My js script:

```
let express = require('express');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const http2 = require('http2');
const fs = require('fs');
const wsport = 8080;
const webport = 443;
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
var lobbies = [];
var helmet = require('helmet');
var rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  max: 100 // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
});

var db = new sqlite3.Database('./database/users.db');


app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(limiter);

db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS emp(UserName TEXT, roomCode TEXT)');

app.post('/Joining', (req, res) => { 
  var  UserName = (req.body.UserName); 
  var  RoomCode = (req.body.RoomCode);    
  db.serialize(()=>{
      db.run('INSERT INTO emp(UserName,RoomCode) VALUES(?,?)', [req.body.UserName, req.body.RoomCode], function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err.message);
        }
        console.log("New user has been added");
        res.send("New user has been added into the database with code = "+req.body.GameCode+ " and Name = "+req.body.UserName);
      });
  console.log(` ${UserName}`)
  console.log(` ${RoomCode}`)

});
});

const server = http2.createSecureServer({
  "key": fs.readFileSync("private.pem"),
  "cert": fs.readFileSync("cert.pem"),
});

server.on("stream", (stream, headers) => {
  const url = headers[":path"];
  let filePath = "";

  if (url === "/") {
    filePath = "public/index.html";
  } else if (url === "/code-screen.css") {
    filePath = "public/code-screen.css";
  } else if (url === "/Joining") {
    filePath = "public/joining.html";
  } else if (url === "/code-screen.css") {
    filePath = "public/code-screen.css";
  } else {  
    filePath = "public/404NotFound.html"
  }
  
  if (filePath !== "") {
    const contentType = getContentType(filePath);

    fs.readFile(filePath, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        stream.respond({ "content-type": "text/plain", "status": 500 });
        stream.end("Internal Server Error");
      } else {
        stream.respond({
          "content-type": contentType,
          "status": 200,
        });
        stream.end(data);
      }
    });
  } else {
    stream.respond({ "content-type": "text/plain", "status": 404 });
    stream.end("File Not Found");
  }
});

function getContentType(filePath) {
  const fileExt = path.extname(filePath);

  switch (fileExt) {
    case ".html":
      return "text/html";
    case ".css":
      return "text/css";
    default:
      return "text/plain";
  }
}

server.listen(webport, () => {
  console.log(`HTTP/2 server started on port ${webport}`);
});

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: wsport }, () => {
  console.log(`WebSocket server started on port ${wsport}`);
});

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  console.log("WebSocket connection established");

  ws.on('message', (data) => {
    data = data.toString(); // convert data to string
    console.log(`Received message: '${data}' with length ${data.length}`);
    
    if (data.replace(/\s+/g, '') === "CL") {
      console.log(`data is sending: = ${data}`);
      const generateCode = (length) => {
        const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
        let code = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length);
          code += characters[randomIndex];
        }
    
        return code;
      }
    
      const code = generateCode(6);
      ws.send(`Your code is: ${code}`);
      console.log(`Your code is: ${code}`);
      lobbies.push(code);
      console.log(lobbies);
      console.log("sent");
    
    } else {
      console.log(`data = ${data}`);
      ws.send('Message received');
      console.log('not sent');
    }
  });
});



wss.on('listening', () => {
  console.log(`WebSocket server listening on port ${wsport}`)
});

wss.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(`WebSocket server error: ${error.message}`)
});

process.on('uncaughtException', (error) => {
  console.error(`Uncaught exception: ${error.message}`);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

The relevant part of the code:

```
var  UserName = (req.body.UserName); 
  var  RoomCode = (req.body.RoomCode);
  app.post('/Joining', (req, res) => { 
    db.serialize(()=>{
      db.run('INSERT INTO emp(UserName,GameCode) VALUES(?,?)', [req.body.UserName, req.body.GameCode], function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err.message);
        }
        console.log("New user has been added");
        res.send("New user has been added into the database with code = "+req.body.GameCode+ " and Name = "+req.body.UserName);
      });
  console.log(` ${UserName}`)
  console.log(` ${RoomCode}`)

});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to load `req.body.GameCode` from the request at your Joining action, but no such element exists. Your `form` has a `roomCode`:

```
    <form action="/Joining" method="post" onsubmit="return checkRoomCode();"> 
      <input class="text" type="text" maxlength="24" name="UserName" id="UserName" placeholder="Enter Username Here"> 
      <input class="text" type="text" maxlength="6" name="roomCode" id="roomCode" placeholder="Enter Room Code Here">
      <button class="joinbutton" type="submit">JOIN</button>
    </form>
```

So, you will need to figure out whether `roomCode` is useful for you and if so, change your server-side accordingly. You will also need to figure out whether `GameCode` is useful for you, in which case you will need to adjust your `form`. My guess would be that `roomCode` in your `form` is the same as `GameCode` and these names mismatch, but you will need to figure this out based on the approach I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding the mistakes, in the code, the problem was me using the wrong port :/